# CC2650STK Raspberry Pi AMQP connection loss from Azure IoT Hub

Tags: azure, raspberry-pi, texas-instruments, raspberry-pi3, azure-iot-hub

We have replicated a project that was on hackster.io:
https://www.hackster.io/eursan/complete-wireless-weather-station-ece694?ref=part&ref_id=13511&offset=1

It's working great but every night at 03:26GMT +2 we get a AMQP error and loose connection and the sensor stops sending data. And since every time you want restart it you have to manually reconnect the sensortag with the Raspberry Pi for it to continue to send data.

I'm thinking this may be an issue with the IoT hub when it flushes it's storage every night but cannot be certain.

This is the error msg we are getting:

```
/home/pi/node_modules/azure-iot-device-amqp/node_modules/azure-iot-amqp-base/lib/amqp_common_errors.js:55
error.amqpError = amqpError;
^

TypeError: Cannot set property 'amqpError' of undefined
at translateError (/home/pi/node_modules/azure-iot-device-amqp/node_modules/azure-iot-amqp-base/lib/amqp_common_errors.js:55:19)
at translateError (/home/pi/node_modules/azure-iot-device-amqp/lib/amqp_device_errors.js:20:13)
at /home/pi/node_modules/azure-iot-device-amqp/lib/amqp.js:52:12
at Amqp.send (/home/pi/node_modules/azure-iot-device-amqp/node_modules/azure-iot-amqp-base/lib/amqp.js:167:25)
at Amqp.sendEvent (/home/pi/node_modules/azure-iot-device-amqp/lib/amqp.js:95:14)
at Client.sendEvent (/home/pi/node_modules/azure-iot-device/lib/client.js:256:19)
at /home/pi/weather/meteo.js:103:32
at /home/pi/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3484:13
at /home/pi/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:365:16
at replenish (/home/pi/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:831:29)
at /home/pi/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:842:29
at /home/pi/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:804:16
at /home/pi/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3481:17
at /home/pi/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:307:31
at /home/pi/weather/meteo.js:94:33
at null.<anonymous> (/home/pi/node_modules/sensortag/lib/cc2650.js:303:7)
```

Anyone have an idea what the reason might be?

Thx

/B

Comment: Hi

I don't think it's related to the service itself. The error that causes the disconnect is unfortunately hidden under a bug in the SDK that we fixed in the latest release. 

Can you try to update to the latest version of the package (1.0.5) and then show us a little more of the code and the logs? Thanks!

Comment: @Bizzmo did it work?

Comment: @SaurabhKirtani sadly no, still isn't working, keep getting the AMQP error every night. I'm gonna try to update and see if it get's fixed.

Comment: @Bizzmo Sure, please update to latest version as mentioned by Pierreca and post back here if it works?

Comment: @SaurabhKirtani, I've updated and now have the sensors running.. hope they don't disconnect again. I'll get back to you in a few days. Thx for your help.

Comment: @Bizzmo can you post the error you see with the latest package? shouldn't be the same as this one

Comment: Hi, sry for not getting back earlier, it works great now. Contacted Microsoft and they found an error that they corrected. Everything works great now thanks all for your help :)